# SQL Server EXEC misinterpreting database name

Tags: sql-server

This: @query = `SELECT Count(*) FROM ReportServer$DEVSVR1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'`
executes fine if copied into new query window. But fails EXEC @query with this error:

> Database 'SELECT Count(*) FROM ReportServer$DEVSVR1' does not exist.

SQL is incorrectly parsing the phrase 'SELECT Count(*) FROM ReportServer$DEVSVR1'
as the database name.

Comment: What you've posted is not valid T-SQL: it's unclear if your `@query` is part of what you're running in SSMS. Please post your **actual** T-SQL within triple-backtick lines. Are you trying to run SQL defined in a string/varchar T-SQL variable? If so, you should be using `sp_executesql` and not `EXEC` (only use `EXEC` for stored-procedures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXEC @query means execute procedure with name that is in @query variable.
You probably want EXEC(@query) which executes the string

Comment: Better yet, use `sys.sp_executesql`. Syntax like `EXEC(@SQL)` promotes injection, as you *can't* parametrise such statements.